# Restrict Derive Macro to Specific Type

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm trying to create a derive macro that will compile when used with Structs, and panic when used with any other type.

However - I'm unsure how to match on type in the derive block.

What's the proper way to go about this? And is this even idiomatic? Or is there a more rustic way to do this?

```
use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use quote::quote;
use syn;

#[proc_macro_derive(MyCustomMacro)]
pub fn my_custom_macro_derive(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {

    // parse TokenStream into syntax tree
    let ast = syn::parse(input).unwrap();

    // implement macro
    match ast.Type.to_string() {
        "Struct" => {
            impl_my_custom_macro(&ast)
        },
        _ => {
            panic!("Can only be used with Structs.");
        }
    }
}

fn impl_my_custom_macro(ast: &syn::DeriveInput) -> TokenStream {
    // snip...
}
```

Comment: `DeriveInput.data` is an enum that tells you what kind of item it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use DeriveInput.data:

```rust
use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use quote::quote;
use syn::DeriveInput;

#[proc_macro_derive(MyCustomMacro)]
pub fn my_custom_macro_derive(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {

    // parse TokenStream into syntax tree
    let ast: DeriveInput = syn::parse(input).unwrap();

    // implement macro
    match ast.data {
        syn::Data::Struct(..) => {
            impl_my_custom_macro(&ast)
        },
        _ => {
            panic!("Can only be used with Structs.")
        }
    }
}

fn impl_my_custom_macro(ast: &syn::DeriveInput) -> TokenStream {
    todo!()
}
```